# Why does my depth test fail on Nvidia cards?

Tags: opengl, java, shaders, lwjgl, depth-buffer

I sent a test version of my in-development game to some friends, and they found out that the Depth Test in OpenGL does not work on Nvidia cards. I'm using LWJGL.

I use my own matrices and send them to the shader, and at the start of evey game loop I use

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT ); // clear the display
```

On an Nvidia card, you can see mountains through other mountains and stuff. On my Radeon HD 6650M it works perfectly fine. Any ideas?

I don't have anything special in the shaders—just some basic lighting calculations. I dont touch the `gl_FragDepth`.

Here's a screenshot (with placeholder textures):

[image: Depth-Test bug on NVidia cards]

I use these calculations for the Projection Matrix:

```
public Matrix4f getProjectionMatrix() {
    // Setup projection matrix
    Matrix4f projectionMatrix = new Matrix4f();
    float fieldOfView = 40.0f;
    float aspectRatio = (float)Display.getWidth() / (float)Display.getHeight();
    float near_plane = 0.1f;
    float far_plane = 1000f;

    float y_scale = coTangent((float) Math.toRadians(fieldOfView / 2f));
    float x_scale = y_scale / aspectRatio;
    float frustum_length = far_plane - near_plane;

    projectionMatrix.m00 = x_scale;
    projectionMatrix.m11 = y_scale;
    projectionMatrix.m22 = -((far_plane + near_plane) / frustum_length);
    projectionMatrix.m23 = -1;
    projectionMatrix.m32 = -((2 * near_plane * far_plane) / frustum_length);
    projectionMatrix.m33 = 0;
    return projectionMatrix;
}
```

Comment: I'll ask a dumb question: did you `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`?

Comment: Yes I did haha :)

Comment: Dumb question vol. 2: Did you create a depth buffer?

Comment: Uhm. No idea. :)

Comment: That depends on the interfacing library you're using. If you're using WGL, you have to set the `cDepthBits` parameter in the `PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR` that you pass to `ChoosePixelFormat()`, and then confirm if you got the right format with `DescribePixelFormat()`. Check [this page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL)) for more information.

Comment: But then it shouldn't work on my Ati Radeon either should it?

Comment: not in a perfect world, but actual driver implementations vary between makers, models, and even versions of the same driver. It is completely possible that the way you initialize your gl context is triggering some undefined behavior, which the ATI driver understands as "create depth buffer" and the nVidia driver understands as "don't create depth buffer". To avoid this you have to be extra verbose on everything, and sometimes even have different code paths for different video cards. Which interfacing library are you using, and on what language?

Comment: I'm using OpenGL with the LWJGL library.

Comment: In that case, there's nothing I can do to help you, sorry. I changed the tags so it's more visible to people familiar with that library.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you request a depth buffer from LWJGL by passing a [PixelFormat](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/PixelFormat.html) to your call of Display.create. Like so:

```
Display.create(new PixelFormat(4,24,0,4));
```

The 24 indicates a 24 bit depth buffer.